# ASP.NET MVC3 Web Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I was forced to switch my hosting from Web Hero because they couldn't support an 'ASP.NET MVC3 Web Application'.  I went with GoDaddy and after bin deploying a number of needed dlls, I can now see my site and web pages.

I have two issues now.  I don't see any of the formatting on www.heathermcinerney.com and the images aren't there.

Comment: jmac, Stack Overflow isn't a forum, so you'll have to put enough detail in your question for people to see what's going on. Consider putting in your configuration for static files as well as anything else important to seeing the picture of what's happening. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why are you using MVC3?  That's quite old...

Comment: @Erik - This is even more disturbing that my original host couldn't handle this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't access the .css, .js, or images folder beneath Content because my web.config that I uploaded had debug set to true (i.e., compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0").

Comment: That's not the reason, debug does not control that.  The problem was likely either a security attribute on your files, or some other configuration entry.

Comment: @Erik - That's the only thing that I changed and then I could see the formatting in the .css, the images, and the other functionality in .js files.  They were all located beneath the Content folder.